# python authenticate with urllib2 and cookielib and get login passed/failed result

Tags: python, urllib2

Here is cut from my code which I use to login into the remote site.
My problem is that I don't know how to handle authentication pass/fail result.

```
def prepareLoginData(self):
    self.post_login_data = urllib.urlencode({
                                                'login': self.user,
                                                'password': self.password,
                                                'Login': 'Login'
                                                })
    return self.post_login_data

def prepareOpener(self):
    cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
    self.opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    for header in self.headers:
        self.opener.addheaders.append(header)
    return self.opener
```

Then I login like below:

```
self.resp = self.opener.open(self.login_page, self.post_login_data)
```

and parse the response  self.resp.read() to check if login passed with regular expression.
How can I get login result based on cookie value? or maybe there is another way?
When auth passed or failed the only thing I see in cj is SESSID which does not give info about auth result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try printing self.resp.headers on successful and failed auth and see if you can spot any differences.

Comment: Another idea would be to subsequently request a resource that only authenticated users can access and catching the error if auth failed.

Comment: The only difference in headers is: "Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" when passed and "Cache-Control: private" when failed. Seems to be not very good solution :(

Comment: "Another idea would be to subsequently request a resource that only authenticated users can access and catching the error if auth failed." - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can look at the source code of the returned page:
In a lot of moderns websites, every xhtml element of the page has an id or a class or is child on an element with an id or a class, so i think you can use an xhtml parser like BeautifulSoup to extract error messages from the website.

BeautifulSoup is verry easy to learn and to use, so you'll probabilly find a solution, but if not, give me the url of the website, and i'll try to write a working code...